# Is there a way to make dynamic url without using page.php?id= type of links?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

I want a dynamic html page where the page url doesn't shows id and other stuffs,

**xyz.com/page.php?id=25** or 
**xyz.com/page.php?name=name-here**

rather than I want the dynamic page link to look like

**xyz.com/page/name-here**

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Yes there is. Configure your _server_ and handle routing in your application.

Comment: Delete this post, and first search for relevant webserver (Apache, etc) and/or SEO posts, and if none found (but you should find some), post in the appropriate forum topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your .htaccess file on your hosting account you can use RewriteRule.

xyz.com/page/id/25 **=>** xyz.com/page.php?id=25

xyz.com/page/name/name-here **=>** xyz.com/page.php?name=name-here

> **RewriteRule:** [Click here for documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)

**NC:** No Case

**L:** Last Rule / no other rules are applied.

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-z]+)/([a-z_A-Z0-9]+) page.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!